# Template metaprogramming: Sum of 1 to n

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

Is there a smart way to calculate a sum of consecutive numbers via template meta programming?
This would be the non template algorithm for e.g 1 to 100.

```
int i = 0;
for (int n = 1; n <= 100; n++)
  i += n;

return i;
```

I thought about using a variadic add function and fill it with a parameter list. However I am not sure how to create a parameter list.

```
// add function
template<typename T>
T add(T a) {
  return a;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
T add(T a, Args... args) {
  return a + add(args...); // a + a + a + .. + add()
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? How did your attempts work or not work? Do you have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us?

Comment: Yes, there is. What did you try?

Comment: I updated the question..

Answer (score 10):

```
template <int n>
struct SumOfNumbers {
  static constexpr int value = n*(n+1)/2;
};
```

Comment: Nice solution, is this also working for negative numbers?

Comment: The problem statement doesn't make sense when `n` is negative. What's the correct answer for `n==-5`? Anyway, we leave extending the solution to negative values of `n` as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 4):

Your code can be executed at compile-time if placed inside a  `constexpr` function.

```
constexpr int sum(int x)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (int n = 1; n <= x; n++)
       i += n;

    return i;
}
```

If you want it in a template, you can just do:

```
template <int n>
struct sum_t {
  static constexpr int value = sum(n);
};
```

Comment: @PaulR: fixed - I was trying to show that you can blindly copy-paste OP's code into a `constexpr` function to make it compile-time friendly, but I was too careless.

Answer (score 2):

While the [answer by Igor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45012599/434551) is a good answer to the problem at hand, the following method is more analogous to a for loop.

```
template <int n>
struct AddHelper { static const int value = n + AddHelper<n-1>::value; };

template <>
struct AddHelper<0> { static const int value = 0; };

template <int n>
int add() { return AddHelper<n>::value; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is with `constexpr`.  `constexpr`, especially in C++14, lets you take your runtime code and make it compile time.

In C++11, you have to get stupid with recursion.  Luckily it is 2017, years after C++14 was released, so you don't have to use C++11.  If you are forced to, you can mark your `template` implementation in the question `constexpr`.

Then

```
template<int...Is>
constexpr int add() { return add(0, Is...); }
```

does the trick if you simply must pass the arguments within `<>`s.

Sometimes people ask these questions when they want a general solution, and picked `add` just for a specific one, not realizing it contains features that makes the question easier.

So failing that, a naive left or right fold over a binary add can work.  The downside to a binary left or right fold is that it has O(n) template instantiation depth and O(n^2) total template name length.  This both bounds the length of the sequence you can add, and makes it very slow and memory consuming.

In C++17, the way to handle that is to use built-in fold operations.  If your binary operation you want to fold over isn't one of the built in ones, use operator overloading and wrapper types to force it to be called when you do a language built-in fold.  This is C++17, and your question is C++11, so I won't go into details.

In C++11, where you have some arbitrary *symmetric* binary operation you want to fold over, you can take a list of stuff and break it down into a binary tree using logarithmic recursion depth.

This is tricky; the basic idea is to write a function that splits a list into two at an index, with a prefix and a postfix list it then tacks on.

Then, in pseudo-code, if we have `where` an index, where `list={L0, Ls...}` only if `L0` is mentioned (otherwise it is just some list).

```
split( where, before, list )
if where=0, answer is before, list
if where=1, answer is before+{L0}, {Ls...}
otherwise, is:
  using tmp[2] = split((where+1)/2, before, list)
  answer is split( where/2, tmp[0], tmp[1])
```

The trick is that we do many instantiations, but the recursion depth is short.

Once we have `split`, we can take a list of elements, build a quick balanced binary tree, and apply your binary operator to each pair of elements and solve the tree in logarithmic depth again.

This is, honestly, more bother than upgrading your compiler.

---

TL;DR: upgrade your compiler to [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) or [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), where this is easy.

Failing that, take your attempt and add `constexpr`.  Now use it as-is, or forward

```
template<int...Is>
constexpr int add()
```

to it.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought about using a variadic add function and fill it with a parameter list. However I am not sure how to create a parameter list.

First of all, I suggest you to follow the Gauss-based solution from Igor Tandetnik (+1).

Second: I don't know how to create list of parameter, but if you accept a `std::integer_sequence` (so a parameter list fixed compile time), starting from C++14 you can use `std::make_integer_sequence`.

In this case, there is no need of recursion for your `add()` function, as you can see in the following example

```
#include <utility>

template <typename T, T ... Is>
constexpr T add (std::integer_sequence<T, Is...> const & a)
 {
   using unused = int[];

   T sum {};

   (void)unused { 0, ( sum += Is, 0 )... };

   return sum;
 }


int main ()
 {
   constexpr int sum1 { (100 * (100 + 1)) >> 1 }; // Gauss
   constexpr int sum2 { add(std::make_integer_sequence<int, 100+1>{}) };

   static_assert( sum1 == sum2, "!");
 }
```

In C++17 the solution is even simpler

```
template <typename T, T ... Is>
constexpr T add (std::integer_sequence<T, Is...> const & a)
 { return ( Is + ... ); }
```